# placing f-strings inside of f-strings

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I have a number 1234567.12.  I'm trying to center it in a field of 20, with 3 decimal places, commas as separators and pad the left and right sides with *.  Here's what I did:  (Python3.11)

```
value = 1234567.12
y = f'{value:,.3f}'
x = f'{y:*^20}'
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
x = f'{f"{value:,.3f}":*^20}'
```

is there a cleaner syntax?

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: Your first snippet is by far the best solution.  You don't want to give headaches to the people who have to maintain your code later (including yourself).

Comment: @MatBailie python 3.11.5 spyder anaconda ide

Comment: Go to Python 3.12, which formalized and improved nested f-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specifications of the [format mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> ```
> format_spec     ::=  [[fill]align][sign]["z"]["#"]["0"][width][grouping_option]["."precision][type]
> ```

you can just put `fill` (`*`), `align` (`^`) and `width` (`20`) before `grouping_option` (`,`):

```
x = f'{value:*^20,.3f}'
```

Comment: Or use that directly with the format function? `x=format(value, '*^20,.3f')`

Comment: The `format` function and f-string share the same format mini-language but are suitable for different use cases. F-strings are generally more readable when the template is static, while `format` is a better choice when the template is dynamically generated or used as a mapping function.